# Executing AoG Intents in Parallel

Tags: node.js, webhooks, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have two intents. When I invoke the first one it plays an audio playback 'endless'. The second intent can be used to vote that playback i.e. like if user likes it and dislike if used doses't. My question is can I invoke both intent in such way that both run in parallel or to be more explicit. The first Intent keeps running while the second records user vote.

```
app.intent('playAudio.intent',(conv)=>{
    // Play audio
});

app.intent('voteAudio.intent',(conv,{vote}{
    // Vote audio playing
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're approaching the question a bit sideways. Keep in mind that Intents aren't "executed". Intents capture *what the user has said*. They do **not** describe how your Action replies to what they have said.

So you may have an Intent that triggers audio to play (on an endless loop?).

You may also want users to be able to interrupt that playback to indicate how they vote about that audio. During any playback (of speech, audio effects using SSML, or a Media Response), the user can interrupt what you're saying by starting with "Hey Google" and then what they have to say. This will be passed along to Dialogflow for processing just like every other Intent.

Just like any other Intent as well, your reply will need to be sent to the user. While you can re-start the audio as part of your reply, the previous audio playing is finished. There is, unfortunately, no reliable way to know at which point it was interrupted or tell it to start at a later point in the audio.

If you're asking if the audio can be played in the "background", the answer is no. Actions on Google is meant to support conversational UIs, which have a back-and-forth between the system and the user.

Comment: Hey that is right, but when I add response to 2nd intent,  say "return" or "conv.ask" the audio stops